# Bootstrap lightbox is not showing a lightbox after a click on link

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with Jason Butz's lightbox. Here is the code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>  
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="A Bootstrap Blog Template">
<meta name="author" content="Billy Halim">
<title>Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-lightbox.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap-lightbox.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <a data-toggle="lightbox" href="#demoLightbox">Open Lightbox</a>
    <div id="demoLightbox" class="lightbox hide fade"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class='lightbox-content'>
        <img src="image.png">
        <div class="lightbox-caption"><p>Your caption here</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is there is a link named " Open lightbox " and also the image. The image initially has appeared. If I click the link, it only can scroll down to point the image, it doesn't appear with a lightbox.

Any solution for this ?

Comment: Can you put the source in  JSfiddle?

Comment: I have no experience with the plugin, but since it's called "Bootstrap lightbox" I assume you have to include Bootstrap as well.

Comment: @DesignStudios Here it is : https://jsfiddle.net/r2hhkof2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fiddle will never work without including jQuery and Bootstrap. They are both required for the plugin to function. With that said, the plugin is no longer maintained and does not seem to work with Bootstrap 3.3.4 but does with 2.3.2, which your code seems to be. You  may want to look into using [this lightbox](http://ashleydw.github.io/lightbox) with 3.3.4.

This is the error in bootstrap 3.3.4

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.$backdrop[0].offsetWidth')
```

Here is a working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/macsupport/8pLt5gx4/) with 2.3.2

Comment: Nice information ! I didn't see the "plugin is no longer maintained.." in Jason Butz website. When I check Github, it is stated there ! Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

For future reference here is a lightbox script that works on bootstrap 3: http://ashleydw.github.io/lightbox/